# How to reference Windows Runtime classes in a Static Library?

Tags: c++, win-universal-app

I am new to programming in C++ on **Universal Windows Platform** and I have a quick question: I created a project of **Static Library (Universal Windows)** in Visual Studio 2015 but I couldn't use those Windows Runtime classes such as `Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow` in that project.

I guess I need to add include directives or references to libraries but I couldn't find information about that. I tried to search MSDN but just found two pages where two headers were mentioned for namespace [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441515.aspx) and [Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441496.aspx).

Does anyone know how to reference Windows Runtime classes in a Static Library?

Comment: Did you add a reference to Windows.md file in you project? Which error are you getting. I use a static library in a UWP app and it works, but some settings should be applied. Let me know which error you get

Comment: No. I didn't have a Windows.md file in my project. Where can I find information about it? The error I got is simply that those namespaces and classes are undefined.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a static library of some OpenGLES code and it needs Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow to create a surface object but does not have to create a window. So it's like in a solution of OpengGLES2 Application (Android, iOS, Windows Universal) moving the OpenGLES code from App.cpp in xxx.WindowsUniversal.Application to a library.

Answer (score 4):

You need to build the project with the /ZW option to allow consuming Windows Runtime Extension in a UWP Static Library:

1. Right click on the project from Solution Explorer
2. Click Properties
3. Select C/C++ -> General
4. Set the "Consume Windows Runtime Extension" to "Yes(/ZW)"
5. Click OK

After applying this option, references to Windows Runtime Extensions appear under the references of the project and you can use Windows Runtime Classes.

However, you may see a linker warning while building the library:

> Debug\pch.obj : warning LNK4264: archiving object file compiled with
>   /ZW into a static library; note that when authoring Windows Runtime
>   types it is not recommended to link with a static library that
>   contains Windows Runtime metadata if you are using a linker released
>   before VS 2015 Update 2

I tested the scenario and it worked fine in debug mode, however, I'm not sure if it is the best way since the /ZW option is off by default unlike other types of UWP projects.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx):

> You can use a native C++ static library in a UWP project, but there
>   are some restrictions and limitations to be aware of. Start by reading
>   this topic about static libraries in C++/CX. You can access the native
>   code in your static library from your UWP app, but it's not
>   recommended to create public ref types in such a static library. If
>   you compile a static library with the /ZW option, the librarian
>   (actually the linker in disguise) warns:

Maybe you should consider wrapping all the code in a Windows Runtime Component or a UWP DLL instead.